# Foursquare get venue details

Tags: foursquare

We are planning to use foursquare api to get venue in a particular city. I want data of all the food outlets in a particular city. I have managed to get the categories list but not sure how to get venues from that particular category in a particular city or area.

Please share some tutorials or document which i can check out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing what you want will be using the Venues Platform for browsing according to a category ID.
Look at [venue search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search.html) API reference.

Example of using it:
I know that `4bf58dd8d48988d11f941735` is nightlife (just picked the first one I saw)

So I will call the API (the ll is someplace in New York):

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7268,-73.9972&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d11f941735&limit=50&intent=browse&radius=1500&your ids/oauth
```

Or use the [explorer](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore.html#req=venues/search?ll=40.7268,-73.9972&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d11f941735%2b&limit=50&intent=browse&radius=1500) to see results right away.

**Important**, read the search API and the parameters used here to alter behavior to your needs.

Another very important thing, the API parameters are case sensitive!! (so if they want categoryId, categoryid will not work :) )

Comment: thanks a lot.. this worked :) is there a particular URL to get the info of a particular venue ?

Comment: Yes, there is, actually more simple than you would think, here is the documentation like: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues